# Input loses focus when value of another input is set dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery in a .NET MVC project.

I use the following code to update a total on my form whenever a key is pressed or the value changes on the Quantity or Amount fields.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#@Html.IdFor(i => i.Form.Qty), #@Html.IdFor(i => i.Form.Amount)')
            .change(calculateTotal)
            .keyup(calculateTotal);
    });


    function calculateTotal() {
        var qty = $('#@Html.IdFor(i => i.Form.Qty)').val();
        var amount = $('#@Html.IdFor(i => i.Form.Amount)').val();

        $('#@Html.Id("TotalCost")').val((qty * amount).toFixed(2));
    }
```

Whenever a key is pressed, the input (either quantity or amount) loses focus. I have narrowed this problem down to the last line in `calculateTotal()`. It seems setting the value of `TotalCost` removes focus from the source input of the event.

I'd like to find a work around.

### EDIT:

As per @Christian Varga's suggestion, further testing has shown that this is not a jQuery problem. Rather it is interference from [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Comment: You should check if there's anything else interfering with your script. Setting the value of an input does not cause the focused input to blur, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/jzaxgse1/1/

Comment: Tip: When debugging, check the rendered source not code used to generate the source for the rendered page.

Comment: @ChristianVarga you were right. See my above edit.

Comment: Nice find. You could create a new issue but it looks like there's quite a few there already. I tested it and it seemed quite buggy, how much of the functionality are you using? You might be better off removing the plugin, and doing loose validation instead.